# Managing reader macros in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, reader-macro

I want to define reader macros in such a way that they affect only a certain package/file.

So far I was able to load those files with

```
(let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
  (load "file.lisp"))
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[named-readtables](http://common-lisp.net/project/named-readtables/) is quite good to manipulate readtables.

EDIT:

You can look at [Clesh](https://github.com/Neronus/clesh) and especially [this commit](https://github.com/Neronus/clesh/commit/393b75e6621a58d4aabc1642d310825667e257f5) to see how I've used `named-readtables` to define a new readtable. So now, instead of using `(clesh:enable)` to use the reader macros, one use `(named-readtables:in-readtable clesh:syntax)`.

Comment: How easy to use is it with slime and asdf?

Comment: @sabof: `named-readtables` is available through `quicklisp` thus you can `(ql:quickload :named-readtables)` and you're done.